# Am I oversimplifying this mixed ANOVA?

Tags: time-series, anova

I have 23 participants who completed 8x3 minutes training periods in each session. Participants completed 12 such sessions. Thus far, I have been averaging the results of these 8x3 training periods in each session and then comparing the averages across the 12 sessions using a mixed ANOVA (there were two different types of training).

I'm just wondering if this feels like an appropriate course of action? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Could you post more information about your design? What do you mean that they completed "8x3 minutes training periods in each session." Where does the 12 sessions come in? Are you interested in tracking over time? What were the two different types of training? What is the overall factorial design, and what factors are within- and between-subjects?

Comment: I understand that you have a repeated-measures ANOVA with one factor `sessions`. That sounds reasonable given your design (i.e., to aggregate the 8x3 trainings per session). It assumes that the 8x3 trainings per sessions are exchangeable (i.e., identical). If not, one needs to think about that. From your question it is unclear where you think the problem is (and I suggest to clarify).

Comment: Also need to consider the repeated measurement from the same participant.

Comment: Thanks; I'll try to elaborate helpfully. So participants were assigned to two different types of training. Participants received training in 8 x 3minute blocks. Each block was the same; but with a small break. On average participants came in for 1 of these sessions over 12 weeks. I'm expecting participants to improve across each of the 8 trials in a session; as well as across the 12 sessions. I've been looking at these in two separate ANOVA's - one of which has been comparing the average (of the 8 trials) across each participant's session. Im just wondering if this seems a logical approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you are simplifying appropriately or oversimplifying.

When you average across periods, you lose information (you always lose information when you average).  Is that information important?  There's no way for us to know.  You'd need to think about what information you are throwing away.

To take a simpler case: Suppose you are doing a simple longitudinal study of, say, weight loss on different diets.  You assign people to different diets and weigh them, say, every week for 2 months.  Now, you *could* just look at overall weight loss. But then you are throwing away information about the trajectories of loss.

I am not sure what you are throwing away in your case.